# Pass arguments inside pushNamedandRemoveUntil in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I pass the argument through a `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil` but it shows text widget must not be null when I try to access the passed parameter.

```
CustomButton(
  buttonText: 'Go',
  buttonClick: () {
    Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      Next.id,
      (route) => false,
      arguments: "123456789",
    );
  },
);
```

```
class Next extends StatefulWidget {
  const Next({this.number});

  static const id = "next";
  final String number;

  @override
  _NextState createState() => _NextState();
}

class _NextState extends State<Next> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            widget.number,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Error is**
Failed assertion: line 298 pos 10: 'data != null'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To pass arguments you need to do the following:

```
 Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage(title : "Hello World")), (route) => false);
```

Here you navigate to `SecondPage` widget and pass the argument `title` to the widget.

Comment: Can I pass only one argument? I need to pass three arguments on how can I do that.?

Comment: U can add more arguments to the constructor. Or just create a class containing all those 3 fields then pass an instance of that class to the constructor of SecondPage

Comment: When I am using this I am getting back button